# Wordpress how to generate list of revisions (post and pages) for public

Tags: wordpress

I need to implement to Wordpress something like Public Revisions. The idea is that for every post and page there'll be a list of revisions (public, not only for logged-in) that allows reader to click to display previous version of post or page. So, I guess there should be a loop to check if there is a revision and print them while there are some. Making the list clickable, and showing the revisions would be awsome.

There was a plugin to do that, but it's abandoned and it doesn't work anymore. In fact, you can't even get it from the official list of plugins for WP.
Please help me achieve it the best (easiest) possible way. Unfortunately, my knowledge of PHP is only basic.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you still need it but perhaps you could have a look at this?
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/post-revisions/#list-post-revisions
Seems like you could retrieve the data and create a page with it.